# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' error for chapter 5 EX15

Tags: python

I am trying to display a bar graph for a file of student scores from chapter 5 EX15 python book by Zelle.  I am not able to get the bar graph to display however.

## Program to plot a bar chart of student exam scores.

## Author: Matthew Jenkins

```
from graphics import*
def main():

    print("This program reads the student scores from a file that you can insert!")
    fName = input("Enter the file name: ")
    inFile = open(fName, 'r')
    numStudents = int(inFile.readline())
    scores = inFile.readlines()
    inFile.close()

    winH = 50 + numStudents * 30
    win = GraphWin('Student Exam Scores', 500, winH)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 100, winH)
    win.setBackground("gray")

    scoreHeader = Text(Point(50, winH * .9), 'Exam Scores')
    scoreHeader.setFill("Blue")
    scoreHeader.draw(win)
    x = 10
    i = 1

    for i in range(10):
        numtxt = Text(Point(x, 1),'%d'%x )
        numtxt.setFill('blue')
        numtxt.draw(win)
        x = x + 10

    y = 1
    for line in scores:
        name, num = line.split()
        y+=1
        bar = Rectangle(Point(40, (y*10)), Point(num, (y*10) + 10)).draw(win)
        
        
        
        print(name, num)
  

        
    

main()
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code displayed; it's saying that the minus (-) operator can't take a string and int as operands, but there is no minus operator in the code shown...  It might be a formatting problem in the file of scores being read, like there's a string where a number should be...

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` variable comes from unpacking the `str.split()` method, which returns a list of strings, resulting in `num` being unpacked as a string. You should convert `num` into an integer before using it to perform numeric operations.

Change:

```
bar = Rectangle(Point(40, (y*10)), Point(num, (y*10) + 10)).draw(win)
```

to:

```
bar = Rectangle(Point(40, (y*10)), Point(int(num), (y*10) + 10)).draw(win)
```